# Location of folders created in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Where do I find the location of the folders and text files I created in windows phone 8. Can we see it in the explorer like we search for the app data in Windows 8? I'm not using `IsolatedStorage`, instead `Windows.Storage`. I want to check if the folders and files are created as I want.

This is how I write the file

```
IStorageFolder dataFolder = await m_localfolder.CreateFolderAsync(App.ALL_PAGE_FOLDER, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile PageConfig = null;

        try
        {
            PageConfig = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("PageConfig.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
        try
        {
            if (PageConfig != null)
            {
                using (var stream = await PageConfig.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.AsOutputStream());
                    writer.WriteString(jsonString);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string txt = e.Message;
            return false;
        }
```

And this is how I read the file from the folder

```
        try
        {
            var dataFolder = await m_localfolder.GetFolderAsync(App.ALL_PAGE_FOLDER);
            var retpng = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("PageConfig.txt");

            if (retpng != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(retpng))
                    {
                        jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    return jsonString;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
        }
```

There are also other folders created. I dont receive any exceptions while writing but when I read the string is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.LocalFolder`[(MSDN link here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx)  is another name for Isolated Storage that is in `Windows.Storage` namespace. The only other location you can access is your app's install directory (and only read-only).

You can use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)  to browse what files are in your app's Isolated Storage, or the command line tool that comes with the SDK.

Comment: Thank you, Some how even though the data is written, When I try to read it back, it fails. Do you think I have gone wrong in write or the read functions written above?

Comment: Once you've confirmed with Windows Phone Power Tools the files are present in the location you expect, try referring to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.LocalFolder` as your `dataFolder`.

Comment: Yes I jus checked, the files are present but its empty !! :(

Comment: The PageConfig.txt is empty, I also have png files written to few other folders. I can see and open them, but the text files are empty. I have modified the writing to text file but the rest is the same! Do i need to convert it to bytes and then write?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Windows Phone Power tools, I figured out that there was no text being written in file.
So I converted string to byte and then wrote it to the file and it works! Don't know why the other one does not work though..

```
using (var stream = await PageConfig.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
   byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);                       
   stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool that comes with Windows Phone SDK 8.0 is **Isolated Storage Explorer** (**ISETool.exe**) which reside in "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool" folder for default installation
ISETool.exe is used to view and manage the contents of the local folder